# Create a multiple choice layout dynamically using a string

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a multiple choice graphic using this string:

```
const text = `This is the body of the question? 1) this is the option one 2) this is the option two 

3) this is the option three 
4) this is the option four
`;
```

So I need to give each option a structure like this probably:

```
<p class="block">1) this is the option 1</p>
```

So I want to automatically create these p tags to have the layout of multiple choice question.

But the issue is I can't find a solution to simply differentiate each option!
The code should look like this:

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

const text = `This is the body of the question? 1) this is the option one 2) this is the option two 

3) this is the option three 
4) this is the option four
`;

let render = '';
render += getSpans(text);
content.innerHTML = render;

function getSpans(text) {
    let result = text;
  result.replace( replace each option with new structure, '<p class="option"></pn>');

  return result;
}
```

```css
.option {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Note that always we have options like 1) some text 2) some text etc...

**NOTE: I need it to be a simple string as the question insist on..**

Comment: Why a single string? Wouldn't an array of strings be a good format? Then you can loop over each string and create an element for each one.

Comment: Yes I know but I need it to be a simple string..

Comment: Can you edit the string so you can easily use a specific character to delimit the question and answers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your final goal is, but if you just want to add paragraph tags like you mentioned, one way to do it is split the string by line breaks, then rebuild it with

tags:

```
function getSpans(text) {
    let result = text.split("\n");
    let output='';
    result.forEach(item => { output += "<p>" + item + "</p>"; });
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I edited the question for the misunderstanding I may have or may have not those breaks...Plus one...

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using structured data to define your question instead of a single string. If you define your question data as an object, then you can easily get the question text and options by accessing the keys directly and iterating over the options. Additionally, you'll be able to define the correct answer by adding another key to `question` like `'correct': 2` for future use.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

const question = {
  'text': "This is the body of the question?",
  'options': [
    "this is the option 1",
    "this is the option 2",
    "this is the option 3",
    "this is the option 4"
  ]
}

let render = renderQuestion(question);
content.innerHTML = render;

function renderQuestion(data) {
  let result = '<p>' + data['text'] + '</p>';
  data['options'].forEach(
    element => result += '<p class="option">' + element + '</p>'
  );

  return result;
}
```

```css
.option {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

But if you absolutely need to parse the string, you can split on the regex `/(\d\) )/` (a digit, a closing parenthesis, a space). Then the first part will be the question text, then every other part will be an option (starting with index 2).

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');

const question = `This is the body of the question? 1) this is the option one 2) this is the option two 

3) this is the option three 
4) this is the option four
`;

let render = renderQuestion(question);
content.innerHTML = render;

function renderQuestion(data) {
  let parts = data.split(/(\d\) )/);
  result = '<p>' + parts[0] + '</p>';

  for (let i = 2; i < parts.length; i += 2) {
    result += '<p class="option">' + parts[i].trim() + '</p>';
  }

  return result;
}
```

```css
.option {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: @Pixier Then could you elaborate on the *why* you need it to be a simple string?

Comment: Because I'm getting this string from a textarea where I type a simple string on ...

Comment: I can't ask my user to type an object because I'm more comfortable with the object to generate the question right?

Comment: I would absolutely ask the user to input the question text and each option separately. Otherwise you're relying on some odd string parsing/splitting to try to assume the end result rather than allowing them to enter the data as the intended use.

Comment: My end users are professional typist and they asked me to do it like this... this is more simple and time friendly for them ....

Comment: @Pixier updated this to parse the string by splitting via regex.

Comment: This working fine except one thing . what if users type the option with breaks between them or between some of them...

Comment: That's exactly the type of issue you would avoid by allowing the user to input separate question text and options. Per your question, it seemed like the format was always going to be `1) option 1 2) option 2`. So if that's not the case, then you'd need to build in other string detection to handle these other cases. You can instruct your end users as much as possible, but at the end of the day you're eventually going to run into these formatting edge cases unless they enter in each question/option text separately.

Comment: @Pixier updated once more to handle newlines too